# Cannot install PyPi library using pipenv

Tags: python, pypi, pipenv

I am trying to install the PyPi names library using pipenv
https://pypi.org/project/names/

The package successfully installs after running:
`pipenv install names`

But I still receive the error message:

```
File "blockchain.py", line 4, in <module>
    import names
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'names'
```

When I try doing:

```
pip install names
```

I get the message :

```
(Blockchain) bash-3.2$ pip install names

Requirement already satisfied: names in /Users/ayunas/.local/share/virtualenvs/Blockchain-xNznGcTc/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.3.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely occurring because the location of your pip install isn't matching the location of the python you're running. `pipenv run pip install names` will install names to your virtualenvironment; `pip install names` installs it to your system python.

You can check this for yourself by opening up a terminal and typing in `where pip` and `where python` and then `pipenv run where pip` and `pipenv run where python`. Note the differences :)